# tcolorbox is not breakable with fix height

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, boxes, tcolorbox

I create the following "empty box" with predefined height. I use the command \emptybox defined below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newcommand{\emptybox}[2][\linewidth]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,
enhanced,
notitle,
height=#2]
  \end{tcolorbox}
}


\begin{document}
\emptybox{15in}  
\end{document}
```

But this box doesn't seem to be breakable between pages ...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather obvious that setting the height of the box does not yield the desired result. However, you can create an empty breakable box that runs over several pages by just adding a number of empty lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{inc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newcommand{\emptybox}[2][\linewidth]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,
enhanced,
notitle]
\setcounter{inc}{0}%
\loop\stepcounter{inc}
~\par
\ifnum\number\value{inc}<#2\repeat
\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}
\emptybox{111}  
\end{document}
```

[image]